# FakeItEasy failed assertion with randomly <ignored> param (and there is a match in the calls)

Tags: unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to implement a unit test with a methodcall assertion. (MustHaveHappened)

I'm using the following code:

```
[Fact]
        public void Should_set_setting_and_map_new_value_for_non_existing_setting()
        {
            //Arrange
            var userSetting = new SettingDetailsBuilder().Build();
            var respository = A.Fake<ISettingsRepository>();
            A.CallTo(() => respository.GetUserSetting(0, 0, null)).WithAnyArguments().Returns(userSetting);
            var dataretriever = new SettingsDataRetriever(respository);

            //Act
            var newUserSetting = dataretriever.SetUserSetting("variableName", "SomeOtherValue", 1, 1, "FST");

            //Assert
            A.CallTo(() => respository.GetUserSetting(1, 1, "variableName")).MustHaveHappened();
        }
```

But I get randomly a failed test, whereby some arguments are mentioned as "ignored". However, the assertion is with exact parameters.

Error:

```
Assertion failed for the following call:
    AlfaProNext.Repositories.Settings.ISettingsRepository.GetUserSetting(1, <Ignored>, <Ignored>)
  Expected to find it at least once but found it #0 times among the calls:
    1: AlfaProNext.Repositories.Settings.ISettingsRepository.Exists(varName: "variableName")
    2: AlfaProNext.Repositories.Settings.ISettingsRepository.GetUserSetting(
          userId: 1,
          profileId: 1,
          variableName: "variableName")
```

Does anybody knows why this is happening randomly?

Comment: I see you also opened FakeItEasy issue [562](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/562) with this question. I've responded there with some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to tests being executed in parallel by XUnit 2.0 while using a FakeItEasy version older than 2.0.0-beta009. The latter includes a fix for [issue 476](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/476), which made argument constraints using `That` and `Ignored` threadsafe.

If feasible, consider upgrading to the latest FakeItEasy. (You can see the latest changes at the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/releases/).) Or turn off parallel test execution in XUnit.

Answer (score 1):

After some great feedback from the FakeItEasy forum, I have my answer. Apparently the current stable version is not threadsafe and cannot handle the latest version of XUnit 2, which is running the tests in parallel.

https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/562

My fix was to upgrade FakeItEasy to version 2 beta 10. (alternative is to run the test in a single thread)